Define an array in C using a macro as length
I want to defined an array, the length from a macro as below,
#define A   (2.5)

#define B   (2.0)

#define LEN (A*B)   // I know LEN is an integer, not decimal numbers

static int array[LEN]  // define an integer array, length is A*B=5

I have a compile check to guarantee that the LEN is an integer,
simply like build_assert( (int)LEN == LEN )
The compiler gives "size of array 'array' has non-integer type", what is the best way to change it?

What other answer than "use integer types instead" do you expect, really? There is no reason to calculate array sizes using decimals.

why?  if we do fft, the sampling rate is 2.5Hz, period is 2, then the number of samples, to save to an array, will be 2.5*2, right?

You should be using the unit mHz or 10th of Hz in that case. When doing engineering, the implementation doesn't need to be a literal copy of the theoretical equations. C programs are written for the benefit of the CPU, not for the benefit of the programmer.

Thank you, it helps!
would these macros be feasible? like:
#define A_10TH (25)
#define B           (2)
#define LEN       ( A_10TH  * B / 10 )

Macros involving floating point numbers are really bad to use for sizing arrays, even if you forcibly cast the value to an integer type.  What if 2.5 * 2.0 turns out to be 4.9999999 or similar instead of the expected 5.0?  Because 4.9999999 converted to an integral value in C is going to be 4, not 5.

BTW, for future proof: #define LEN ((A)*(B))

Thanks for the suggestions.  I will not define floating point numbers in macros for the size of array.  Thank you, really helpful!

This method should work:
#define A   (2.5)
#define B   (2.0)
/* If you want to round,define it like this: 
       #define LEN(x) ((size_t)(x+0.5))
   If you sure LEN has two arguments and you
   don't care it may result in allocating a
   little more space, define it like this:
       #define LEN(a, b) (((size_t)(a)+1)*((size_t)(b)+1)))
*/
#define LEN(x) ((size_t)(x))
static int array[LEN(A*B)];


Until the point where the number isn't exactly representable in floating point format anyway. Then it will break.

This will not work in all conforming C implementations because (size_t)((2.5)*(2.0)) is not an integer constant expression. C 2018 6.6 6 says floating-point constants in an integer constant expression must be the immediate operand of a cast, but 2.5 and 2.0 are not immediate operands of a cast; they are operands of *. 6.7.6.2 4 says if the size in an array declaration is not an integer constant expression, the array type is a variable length type. 6.7.6.2 2 says if an identifier is declared to be an object with static storage duration, it shall not have variable length array type.
